# Privileges discrepancy

Tags: mysql

When I am logged in as `rds_user` and have following privileges:
`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DROP ON`news`.* TO 'rds_user'@'%'`

My code runs `INSERT` command just fine, but when it gives ProgrammingError it executes `UPDATE` instead. However, `UPDATE` command errors out with
`1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user 'rds_user'@'XX.XX.XX.XX' for table 'data'`

`data` is a table in db `news`

I tried granting privilege again and flushed privileges, still same error. I am using Python's sql connector to send the commands. Genuinely confused on what is going

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'rds_user'@'%';`

Answer (score 0):

You're logged in as rds_user, but you may not actually be logged in as 'rds_user'@'%'.

Privileges are actually granted not just per-username, but per username/host combination.  When you log in, you may be logging in as rds_user associated with a specific host, and that user may have less privileges.

Log in and run `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` to see which user you're actually logged in as.

Run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'rds_user';` to see all the users you could be logged in as.